# Position of Done button on iOS WebViews

Tags: ios, modal-view

On iOS modal screens, I’m following a pattern of always positioning key/affirmative actions on the **right** (Save, Add, etc) and dismissive actions on the **left** (Done, Cancel, Close). However, if a dismissive action is the only action on the modal, it will be positioned on the right.

On iOS WebViews, it’s standard to have a refresh icon allowing users to reload/refresh the page. Most WebViews have this refresh icon positioned on the right, while a Done button is positioned on the left. This follows the logic mentioned above, however, my assumption is that closing the WebView (i.e. selecting Done) would be much more common and used compared with the refresh action on the right. Would it make sense to swap the positions here and have Done on the right? Or would such exception be inconsistent with iOS patterns?